# Error incomprensible

Tags: oracle, plsql

Me da un error al ejecutar el siguiente codigo:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ListaPrimos (n1 IN number, n2 IN number) AS
    metodo number;
BEGIN 
    if n1<n2 
    then
   metodo := n1;
    while (metodo <= n2)
        loop
            if primo(metodo) then 
                dbms_output.putline("metodo");
                else 
                metodo := metodo +1;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end if;
END;
/
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
5/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "METODO" when expecting one of
         the following:
         . ( * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem then
         <an exponent (**)> and or || multiset
         The symbol "then" was substituted for "METODO" to continue.
```

Agraderia mucho que me ayudasen a solucionar el problema

Comment: `dbms_output.putline("metodo");`  metodo ahi es un string y no el `metodo` que tienes declarado anteriormente

Comment: Voto para cerrar como *error tipografico* porque es un fallo al escribir el codigo y no el desconocimiento de la sintaxis (usa bien el `if then` en otras lineas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el

```
if n1<n2
```

te falta poner `then`

En

```
dbms_output.putline("metodo");
```

debería ser

```
dbms_output.put_line("metodo");
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias , has sido muy amable